# Is Linq to Entities an ORM?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I am creating an article about Linq to entieies but cannot get a definite answer if Linq to entities is an ORM. Is linq to enties an ORM?

Comment: LINQ to Entities is only part of the functionality of Entity Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is an ORM.

It **M**aps **O**bjects to **R**elation databases.

Comment: If one wanted to be very particular, Linq to Entities *only* involves the query side, and could therefore be said to *only* map Relational databases to objects, but not the other way around, making it not exactly an ORM.

Comment: @qes: What do you mean? EF can generate databases.

Comment: Where in the question was EF mentioned at all?  All I see asked about is Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your definition of ORM.  It is a broad term that can or cannot include several functional aspects of a tool.

If you are writing an article, it would probably be more valuable to your readers to break down in more discreet and explicit terms what it does and does not do that other similar tools do, rather than to simply state if it is or is not an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

**Entity Framework is an ORM.** LINQ to Entities is only one of LINQ implementations.